# weblogic freeze and block all processing thread

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

We deploy our web application onto weblogic server 10.3.6. We try to run a stress test on our server. But sometime there a thread which do something we do not know yet, making the whole weblogic server freeze and does not process any request nor running thread, except only that thread.

We try and find out one of the reason is jxl library which call GC when read, create new file. After we disable it, our application run much more smoother. But it still freeze for some other reason.

So i want to ask is there a way to find out what our server doing at freezing time? Or is there any possible reason for the whole server to freeze like when they call GC?

Comment: You can try to grab a thread dump and see if there's an obvious culprit.

Comment: @shmosel: is it possible ? since whenever it freeze, even weblogic console page freeze as well.

Comment: You should start with using any profiler tool to look at jvm state when it freezes. Specifically look at the thread status and memory. You can also obtain thread dump with `kill -3` from frozen jvm.

Comment: @Setu : is there other way like tail the log file ? Since it is not our but customer server. They did not grant us any privilege to do anything there except copy file to a certain folder. And then give us an account to weblogic console to update war file and reset application. And these problem only happen on their server.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that for looking into jvm state. Having access to web console for frozen jvm is useless. If you can't have access then their weblogic server admin should provide you with thread and heap dumps.